# java.io.FileNotFoundException in Java code

Tags: java

I'm using this code to read Linux SWAP spaces:

```
public void getSwap() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\/A-Za-z0-9]+)[\\s]+([a-z]+)[\\s]+([0-9]+)[\\s]+([0-9]+)[\\s]+([\\-0-9]+).*");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/swaps"));
        String s = reader.readLine();
        while (s != null)
        {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            if (matcher.matches())
            {
                System.out.println(s);
                System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
                System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
            }
            s = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    }
```

I want to modify the code to return null when there is not file /proc/swaps. I don't want to interrupt the code when file is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can very easily create a file object and use the .exists() method to check its existence (and its isDirectory() method to make sure its not a directory) in advance of the buffered reader creation.

Then you could take any action you wanted if it did not exist.

In response to your request for code: I didn't try to compile this, but it should work like so:

```
File file = new File("/proc/swaps");
if (!file.exists()) {
    System.err.println("/proc/swaps did not exist!");
    return null;
}
else if (file.isDirectory()) {
    System.err.println("/proc/swaps is a directory, not a file.");
    return null;
}
```

You should also wrap your function in a `try { } catch() {}` and handle the exception with a comment that it can't occur since you checked existence before-hand.  This way you don't have to declare that the function throws a checked exception.

Comment: Could you show me some code sample?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html